proxy for 3d array, knowing the two indexes of array inside the handler function
I have this JavaScript Proxy code which I want to trigger the set handler that can tell me the first and second keys.
This means that when I try to set globalVar.a.b = "55b" only the line prop == "a.b" would be triggered. Now it's trigger only using the 2nd key.


let globalVar = [];
const handler = {
  get(target, name) {
    const v = name in target ? target[name] : (target[name] = {});
    return typeof v == "object" ? new Proxy(v, handler) : v;
  },
  set(target, prop, val) {
    if (prop == "a") {
      console.log("myObject[" + prop + "] setto " + val);
    } else if (prop == "b") { //getting triggered 
      console.log("myObject[" + prop + "] setto " + val);
    } else if (prop == "c") { //getting triggered 
      console.log("myObject[" + prop + "] setto " + val);
    } else if (prop == "a.b") { //want to get something like this
      console.log("myObject[" + prop + "] setto " + val);
    }
    target[prop] = val;
  }
};
globalVar = new Proxy(globalVar, handler);

globalVar.a.x = "55a";
globalVar.a.b = "55b";
globalVar.a.c = "et4";



